# How to make an Express site without a template engine?

Tags: express

I do not want Jade or EJS on my site. How can I create an express site without it defaulting to the Jade templates? Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If what you want is directly to serve static html files with the possibility to cache resources, while still being able to hit "/" and get index.html, then the answer is as easy as this:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Gotcha: Html files including index.html must be inside /public folder instead of /views

Comment: Use path.join(__dirname, 'public') instead of assuming '/' is the correct directory separator.

Comment: This what actually i need. Because i intend to consume the data via Go.

Answer (score 28):

You could use commands below to install [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) globally and then scaffold a project without a view engine

```
 npm install -g express-generator
 express newProject --no-view
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, if you need to start from scratch. I would just add `--git` to generate a `.gitignore` file

Answer (score 5):

You can comment out the lines

```
app.set 'views', __dirname + '/views'
app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
```

from the Express initialization code.

If you are serving only static content: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/static-files/index.js

Otherwise, use your database, your files, your user input, or whatever to concatenate a string that will make up the http response.

```
// Express 3.x
app.get('*', function(req,res){
  fs.readFile('./foo.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    data += (req.query['something'] || "")
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.send(200, data);
  });
});
```

With that said: I have grown to love Jade as I've been playing with it for the past few months. It has its idiosyncracies but it's orders of magnitude faster to write any  complicated html.

Answer (score 2):

With Express 4.0.0, the only thing you have to do is comment out 2 lines in app.js:

```
/* app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade'); */ //or whatever the templating engine is.
```

And then drop your static html into the /public directory. Example: /public/index.html

Comment: This might be obsolete now. Things change fast.

Comment: Things are working this way, but Error: Cannot find module 'html' - popping every time

Comment: Once you comment the above lines, add the jade version files to public folder and also make changes in "app.js" or "main.js" file in public folder where $routeProvider function is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Use Restify
http://restify.com/

```
var restify = require('restify'),
fs = require('fs');

var server = restify.createServer({
  certificate: fs.readFileSync('path/to/server/certificate'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/server/key'),
  name: 'MyApp',
});

server.listen(8080);
```

It borrows heavily from Express -Routing

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to generate express app without view is:

```
npx express-generator --no-view
```

It will generate the following folder structure and files:

[image: Express generated folders and files.]